# Simple generic linq expression generation method

Tags: c#, linq

Here is my generic method for creating linq expression based on field name of a type, operator (as enumerations of operators generated from XSD) and value of field

```
  private Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetCriteriaPredicate<T>(string fieldName, OperatorRef selectedOperator, string value)
    {

        PropertyDescriptor prop = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(GoodsWorksService)).Find(fieldName, true);

        if (prop != null)
        {
            //value as object
            object fieldValue = null;

            //GUID
            if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(Guid?))
            {
                fieldValue = new Guid(value) as Guid?;
            }

            //Integer
            if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(int?) || prop.PropertyType == typeof(int))
            {
                int intValue;

                if (Int32.TryParse(value, out intValue))
                {
                    fieldValue = intValue;
                }
            }

            //DateTime
            if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?) || prop.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                DateTime dateTimeValue;

                if (DateTime.TryParse(value, out dateTimeValue))
                {
                    fieldValue = dateTimeValue;
                }
            }

            //String
            if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                fieldValue = value;
            }

            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

            switch (selectedOperator)
            {
                // "="
                case OperatorRef.Item:
                    {                            
                        var body = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameter, prop.Name), Expression.Constant(fieldValue, prop.PropertyType));

                        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
                    }
                // "!="
                case OperatorRef.Item1:
                // "<>"
                case OperatorRef.Item2:
                    {                           
                        var body = Expression.NotEqual(Expression.Property(parameter, prop.Name), Expression.Constant(fieldValue, prop.PropertyType));

                        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
                    }
                // "<"
                case OperatorRef.Item3:
                    {                           
                        var body = Expression.LessThan(Expression.Property(parameter, prop.Name), Expression.Constant(fieldValue, prop.PropertyType));

                        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
                    }
                // "<="
                case OperatorRef.Item4:
                    {                            
                        var body = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(Expression.Property(parameter, prop.Name), Expression.Constant(fieldValue, prop.PropertyType));

                        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
                    }
                // ">"
                case OperatorRef.Item5:
                    {                            
                        var body = Expression.GreaterThan(Expression.Property(parameter, prop.Name), Expression.Constant(fieldValue, prop.PropertyType));

                        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
                    }
                // ">="
                case OperatorRef.Item6:
                    {                            
                        var body = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(Expression.Property(parameter, prop.Name), Expression.Constant(fieldValue));

                        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
                    }
                //By containing string in field
                case OperatorRef.LIKE:
                    {                            
                        MethodInfo contains = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains");

                        var body = Expression.Call(Expression.Property(parameter, prop.Name), contains, Expression.Constant(fieldValue, prop.PropertyType));

                        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
                    }
                // по умолчанию - "="
                default:
                    {                            
                        var body = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameter, prop.Name), Expression.Constant(fieldValue, prop.PropertyType));

                        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
                    }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid nesting where possible.

> ```
> if (prop != null)
> {
> }
> ```

Should be:

```
if (prop == null) { return null; }
```

---

> ```
> //GUID
> if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(Guid?))
> {
>      fieldValue = new Guid(value) as Guid?;
> }
> ```

Use variables instead of comments where possible and makes sense.

```
 var isGuid = prop.PropertyType == typeof(Guid?);
 if (isGuid)
 {
      fieldValue = new Guid(value) as Guid?;
 }
```

or

```
var isInt = prop.PropertyType == typeof(int?) || prop.PropertyType == typeof(int);
if (isInt) {... }
```

---

Name your constatnts/enums properly so that you don't have to comment them.

> ```
> OperatorRef.Item
> ```

Should be

```
OperatorRef.EqualSign
```

or instead of

> ```
> OperatorRef.Item1
> OperatorRef.Item2
> ```

you do

```
 OperatorRef.NotEqualCSharp
 OperatorRef.NotEqualVB
```

and so on...

---

You should create another method that parses/converts the `value` into the property type and put the `if`s there.

Comment: Good stuff, though I'd hope `if (blah == typeof(Guid))` is obvious enough to not require either comment or variable.

Comment: @eurotrash you're right, if I had only a single `if` I'd put the short condition inside the it but if I had several `if`s with multiple conditions then for the sake of consistancy I'd probably create a helper variable anyway ;-)